# How do I preseed a pointopoint option in Debian?

Tags: debian, automated-install, preseed

How can I preseed a pointopoint connection for the Debian installer?

The following option didn't work.

```
d-i netcfg/get_pointopoint string 10.10.10.10
```

I need it because the default gateway for the new VM I create is outside the VMs Subnet.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your purpose is to use something like a PPP or PPPoE connection?

If you look at http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=694965 you find the following:

> > There already seems to be some code in static.c like the code below,
> >     but it doesn't seem to be working
>
> Well, it's only triggered for known point-to-point devices:
>
> ```
>             if (strncmp(iface->name, "plip", 4) == 0
>                 || strncmp(iface->name, "slip", 4) == 0
>                 || strncmp(iface->name, "ctc", 3) == 0
>                 || strncmp(iface->name, "escon", 5) == 0
>                 || strncmp(iface->name, "iucv", 4) == 0)
>                 state = GET_POINTOPOINT;
> ```

Judging from that, in order to make it work I think you may need to preseed the following to one of the above, such as "plip":

```
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select plip
```

Comment: Well this isn't what I want to do. I've edited my question so I hope ist now more clear what I want.

Comment: In that case it's not going to work. I would suggest to find a different solution.